# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - webpack sample Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

I am facing an issue in webpack sample while getting webpack build:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

**package.json**

```
"build": "rimraf dist && node_modules\\.bin\\webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail",
```

Comment: try node --max_old_space_size=4096  option

Comment: Thanks @Kasiriveni . I already used it at ngc.cmd, but still am facing this.

Comment: Please update to the latest version of npm
npm install -g npm@latest

Comment: In the webpack.config file try commenting or removing  devtool:'source-map'

Answer (score 0):

Every single time when i got the same error i  managed to solve the issue using the  `--max_old_space_size` option.

My guess would be that either `--max_old_space_size=4096` is not enough (just use a higher value) or that the option is not applied in the right place.

I would try:

```
"build": "rimraf dist && node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules\\.bin\\webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail"
```